# Background Image flickers on page load, only in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, pageload, flicker

I've come across an issue that only seems to occur when using Chrome, I'm attempting to load a background image onto my webpage but it seems to load once the rest of the content has loaded which includes images. I have tested different file formats, resolutions as well as loading the website in Edge and IE so I assume it is something to do with how Chrome interprets my code.

The beginning of my CSS where I insert the background image.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HeaderFont';
src: url("Fonts/GenBasB.ttf") format('truetype');
}
body {
    background-image: url("Images/Background.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    font-family: 'HeaderFont';
    font-size:120px;
    color:#443a31;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be the webfont download blocking things. Check the timeline in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @CBroe I've looked at it and some images are loaded, then some paint is rasterized. After that it loads another image - assuming background image and finally rasterizes paint again.  Is there a way of changing the way Chrome loads the code? Thanks for your suggestion! :)